# Having an N element output from rejection sampling for N elements

Tags: python, numpy

I am applying a rejection sampling for N elements given probability density function `pdf`. When applying this method for N elements, it is likely that you will return an array of values that has less number of elements compared to the N number you are evaluating, which is from applying the rejection method without looping for values of `condition` that are `False`.

In order to reconcile this, I can try and loop the values that does not meet the `condition` until they are `True`. However, I am not sure on how to loop the condition until the number of elements in my array has the same length with the number of values N given the functions I have defined.

```
import numpy

N = 1000 # number of elements
x = np.linspace(0, 200, N) 
pdf = pdf(x) # some pdf


# Rejection Method #1
# -------------------
fx = np.random.random_sample(size=N) * x.max() # uniform random samples scaled out
u = np.random.random_sample(size=N) # uniform random sample
condition = np.where(u <= pdf/pdf.max())[0] # Run first rejection criterion that returns bool values
x_arr = fx[condition] 

# Here, len(x_arr) < N, so I want to fix it until len(x_arr) == N
while len(x_arr) < N:
    ...
    if len(x_arr) == N:
        break
```

After this, I am having trouble forming a method of iterating until `len(x_arr) = N`.

Comment: Hmm, not exactly sure what you're asking but you can always append an inconsequential (maybe?) padding to your x_arr within the while loop to increase length.

Comment: I edited my post. You pretty much said what I want to try and do. However, I'm having trouble following the iteration process for `condition==False`. I'm to based it off of the length argument `while len(x_arr) < N`, and then loop over everything until actually `len(x_arr)==N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using boolean and advanced indexing. It keeps a list of indices at which values were rejected and redraws these values until the list is empty.

Example sampling and accept/reject functions:

```
def sample(N):
    return np.random.uniform(-3, 3, (N,))

def accept(v):
    return np.random.rand(v.size) < stats.norm().pdf(v)
```

Main loop:

```
def draw(N, f_sample, f_accept):
    out = f_sample(N)
    mask = f_accept(out)
    reject, = np.where(~mask)
    while reject.size > 0:
        fill = f_sample(reject.size)
        mask = f_accept(fill)
        out[reject[mask]] = fill[mask]
        reject = reject[~mask]
    return out
```

Sanity check:

```
>>> counts, bins = np.histogram(draw(100000, sample, accept))
>>> counts / stats.norm().pdf((bins[:-1] + bins[1:]) / 2)
array([65075.50020815, 65317.17811578, 60973.84255365, 59440.53739031,
       58969.62310004, 59267.33983256, 60565.1928325 , 61108.60840388,
       64303.2863583 , 68293.86441234])
```

Looks roughly flat, so ok.